# laravel 5 - enable caching of local asset files

Tags: php, google-chrome, laravel, caching, laravel-artisan

I'm currently developing an App with Laravel 5, and I ran into the following problem:

When I include a, for example, .js file from a foreign server, the script is loaded with a 304 not modified - which is fine. It loads in 146ms according to chrome's network tab.
When I include a local asset, with {{ asset('path to asset') }} I always get a 200, and it takes considerably longer (about 800ms) to load the file.

How can I manage to cache the assets files? I guess it's a browser or webserver issue.

- Brower: Chrome 43.0.2357.52
- Webserver: I'm using the artisan built-in webserver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Artisan server is not meant for production usage - it's simply a development server. It doesn't cache, and it's not meant to. You don't want things caching when you're developing because that will prevent your changes from making it to the browser.

When you are in production using an actual server, like Apache or Nginx, it should handle caching for you. They are both very flexible and have a heap of configuration options for how they cache static assets. It's worth having a look at the boilerplate configurations for those web servers on the [HTML 5 Boilerplate repo](https://github.com/h5bp) as they give you a lot of sane settings out of the box.

You're better off letting your web server handle the caching of assets rather than putting that work onto Laravel. It is a hell of a lot faster for a web server to send back a static asset (or a `304` response) than it is to load PHP, bootstrap the framework and then determine the appropriate response.

Comment: I knew Artisan was for production only, but production becomes hideous if the page load increases that much if you add some assets to it. And some assets, like jquery, bootstrap etc. don't tend to change (and if they do, I know better to clear my cache myself).

Comment: No, the Artisan server is *not* meant for production. You could look at using a CDN for third party assets you don't want to serve yourself (like jQuery or Bootstrap). Otherwise, consider using Laravel's homestead or another virtual server environment that would use Apache/Nginx for local development and give you better caching of non-changing assets.